# Dream or reality? Domain driven design in large data applications

Tags: performance, architecture, domain-driven-design, large-data

I am a fan of domain driven design, I always try to persuade companies to use DDD but It is always rejected because of it's poor performance! currently I have been working on a project with a large data. some of the store procedures take more that an hour to completed. Is it possible to use DDD with this kind of projects? I guess it takes one day to run that SP in domain models even without ORM!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, with proper design and CQRS. You need experienced ppl though..

Comment: What kind of processes are you performing? In rare cases, I believe that performance could be an obstacle to DDD, yes.

Comment: If you use CQRS and event sourcing with a query model and table per view then performance can be very good. Queries are built incrementally (with eventual consistency) as opposed to waiting for a huge query to complete

Comment: Performance of Table driven, Table per form with or without CQRS is fine. Applying Domain driven design patterns ruin the performance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why domain driven design ruins performance. In my experience it adds a few extra mapping layers DB <-> Persistence Model <-> Domain Model. The mapping overhead tends towards zero when factored against round trips to a database.

Comment: The gap between relational DB and Domain model won't fill with couple of extra mappings, domain model is not optimized for read.we have 1000000+ transaction per day over 5000 tables. without Views and store procedures it won't be possible. if you use SP or view you are doing DDD wrong!